# Xamarin UiTest - How to connect mac machine and run iOS app from windows VS 2019

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin UiTest, in which i am not able to run my test in iOS. can someone help on this.

Says error as :iOS cannot be supported on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-ios-simulator?tabs=vswin):

> It is **not possible** to run local iOS tests on Windows so far.

You need to run UITest for iOS app in [Visual-Studio for mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-ios-simulator?tabs=vsmac).

There is also a [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/574) about this question you can follow.

Comment: I have a remote mac machine, in which I'm able to pair that machine, but simulator is not triggered.  Following is the code , I'm getting the error..ConfigureApp.iOS.DeviceIp("**.**.***.**").Debug().InstalledApp("*.ipa").DeviceIdentifier("E4478901 -3650-406E-9221-AE6344EF6DBC").StartApp();

Comment: @Vijayas I mean you can’t do UITest in Visual Studio for Windows. It is not supported so far. You can only do that in Visual studio for Mac

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer so that we can help more people with same problem:).